# How do i manipulate the referrer for RedirectToPage for a page-handler?

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect

My scenario is very simple.

- I have an Overview page where i can create a layout.
- I have an Add page where i can enter essentials.
- I have an Edit page where i can manipulate specifics
- My MasterLayout has a back button which utilizes `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"]`

The screenshot is on the Add page.

When i add my Layout i want to alter the Referer, so when i get forwarded to ./Edit the referrer should be set to another page, instead of ./Add - for the sake of the example google, but in reality it should be the Overview page.

Do i need to write custom middleware for this?

update:
this does not work - the url works, but adding the referer like that does not.

```
var linkGenerator = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<LinkGenerator>();
var url = linkGenerator.GetPathByPage("/LayoutEngine/Administration/Overview");

HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Referer", url);
HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"] = url;
```

[image]

Comment: `Referer` is a *request* header, and as such, can only be set by the client. In other words, you can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers are valid only for the current response. When you set a redirect the current response contains your custom header but when the browser follows the redirect location those headers are no longer present, you need to sent the Overview value as query string to the Editpage:

```
  .........
  var url = linkGenerator.GetPathByPage("/LayoutEngine/Administration/Overview");
  .........
  return RedirectToPage("./Edit", new{id = result.Result, returnUrl = url});
```